# Troubles with com.apple.cmio.AppleCameraAssistant

Tags: terminal, permission, launchd, camera

I've got a problem with the Daemon `com.apple.cmio.AppleCameraAssistant`.

After some researches on my side, I've finally found the problem on why UserEventAgent took so much of my CPU.

Because of this:

`com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.cmio.AppleCameraAssistant[76253]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/AppleCa meraAssistant`

When I `sudo launchctl unload ./com.apple.cmio.AppleCameraAssistant.plist`, I don't have any trouble anymore. However, my camera doesn't work anymore (which makes sense).

I also tried to start by myself the application `/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/AppleC ameraAssistant`, it works like a charm, the camera works.

So my problem is `com.apple.cmio.AppleCameraAssistant.plist` can't start `/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/AppleC ameraAssistant` and I don't know why.

However, in the .plist, I've removed the GroupName and UserName, and it works.

What's the problem so? These lines shouldn't be there or "_cmiodalassistants" doesn't have permission to start "AppleCameraAssistant"?

Permissions are:

.rw-r--r-- root  8 Jan 16:07 com.apple.cmio.AppleCameraAssistant.plist

.rwxr-xr-x root  8 Jan 15:48 AppleCameraAssistant

Do you have any idea why? I'm on 10.13.2

Thank you.